# Simple ASP.NET MVC example

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, repository-pattern

i need some advice on building a real environment MVC project.

I already went thru all the tutorials in asp.net. But i found that most of the tutorials are using ninject, Entity Framework(EF) or linq to sql(L2S)... But i do not want to use 3rd party solution or some others "new" language.

My requirements:

1. i want to connect DB using connectionstrings :

   `<connectionStrings>
   <add name="SQLConn" connectionString="Data Source=MyPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>`
2. A CRUD page which grab from Database using the above connectionstring(SQLConn), with a listing page, update, delete and create new record page + validation at Model.
3. I prefer to have a raw repository pattern, instead of using EF, L2S or some others "extra" tools. i want to use "SELECT * FROM tblTest...".
4. i do not want to include SQL query everywhere on my page, i prefer include all of them in Model.

My problems:

1. `public SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("SQLConn");` This method seems only working in webform pattern, may be i make a mistake.
2. How to develop in Repository pattern with Model validation?

I just need some ideas how to make all these link up together. With the List page as example is good enough. or any sites/blogs for me to refer? Example with MVC 3 is fine too.

Thanks.

Jason

Comment: Try looking at the Nerd Dinner example on codeplex

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In `CustomerDAL` class, you can direclty use `SqlConnection` instead of Linq2Sql

Comment: Possible to combine BLL and DAL into one, Model??

Comment: @Jason Goh yes and it is more bettor to move Model to new Project so that it can be used in other projects like web service etc